# Inserting image in a two column word page

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a report in a 2 column page format. Now I want to insert a rather large picture that requires to use full width of the page and cut the columns horizontally. How can I achiveve this? Please see the images below for what I mean :

[image: normal]

[image]

Comment: Can you please better describe what you're trying to accomplish? Based upon your question, it appears that you've already been able to insert a picture across two columns. Do you want the text to wrap top and bottom of the picture?

Comment: No, in the second image I just drawed a rectangle in photoshop! I want to do the same with an image inside the word iteself.

Comment: Ok, then see my answer, step 1 for the basic image inserting.  The second two steps will help clean up the text flow above and below the image.  Good luck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're looking to have your text read left to right columns above the image, and begin left to right again after the image (rather than left top to bottom, right top to bottom), all you need to do is add two breaks.

1. Insert your image, `Insert > Picture`, then `Format > Wrap Text > Top & Bottom` will insert your image and apply the basic, proper formatting.
2. Insert a Column Break in the left column where you want your image (this forces the text to the next column).
3. Insert a Continous Section Break in the right column immediately above the image's location (this pushes the text back to the left column, but below your image).

In the sample image, there is a column break after paragraph 2 (before image) and a section break (continuous) after paragraph 4 (before image).

[image]

Comment: It has been a long time :) but I forgot to comment "+1 for the penguins"

Answer (score 5):

Select picture -> Wrap Text -> Top and Bottom

Comment: How to add the caption then ?

Answer (score 1):

There is one more step for Ivo Flipse's answer:

After inserting the image, drag it to the position you want and make it as big as wish, then apply step 2 and 3, break column, and continuous.

you might find the break column and continuous tools in page layout ribbon.

Comment: It's actually dav's answer, Ivo Filpse had edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a text box and put the image in there, and text will wrap around and you can move it to wherever you want.